# Setting up another domain controller with Active Directory, Group Policy, DNS

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns

I was wondering if anyone could give me advice on setting up another domain controller. Our environment has one and we're looking to add a second one. I haven't set one of these up before and am thinking of buying a copy of Server 2019 std and installing the roles. I want to do this right and understand what's going on as well as be able to integrate it into our existing environment properly.

Are there any recommended resources for learning about how to do this properly? I have done this in a test VM by just using the wizard and installing the roles.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Thats it, you did it right. If your network infrastructure (DNS!) is set up correctly, there is nothing to do after installing the roles and promoting the new DC.

If you want to start with AD, there are *a lot* of ressources on the net. The official ones are the MOCs (Microsoft official curriculum), which will lead you to the appropiate certification. Other than that, there are thousans of youtube videoss, books, audiobooks, twitch streams and websites to help you out.